# 10’ steel H beam cantilever

Tags: decking

Im trying to create a deck off my sunroom that will be at the pools edge. The deck will be 27’ L x 10’ W (from the sunroom glass doors) and the deck will be a height of 10’. Trying to calculate the size and number of steel beams I’ll need to accomplish the 10’ cantilever. My sunroom is 12’ W x 27’ L and was poured with 4” concrete.

Comment: A drawing would be nice and this will probably need a permit and a working building plan signed off by someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: just as impoant will be the stresses on the existing structure.